# Trying to add additional EBS volumes to MarkLogic Cluster Cloud Formation Template

Tags: aws-cloudformation, marklogic

New the Yaml and Cloud Formation.  Trying to utilize MarkLogics [template](https://marklogic-releases.s3.amazonaws.com/9.0-latest/mlcluster.template) for deploying a clustered MarkLogic DB utilizing our own VPC.  We have the cluster working but have gotten to the point where we would like to mount an additional volume to save backups too.

Were added additional volumes:

```
 MarklogicVolume1root:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Volume'
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [0, !Ref AZ]
      Size: !Ref VolumeSize
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MarkLogic-GroupA-Host1-Volume1Aroot
      VolumeType: !Ref VolumeType
      Encrypted: !If [UseVolumeEncryption, 'true', 'false']
      KmsKeyId: !If [HasCustomEBSKey, !Ref VolumeEncryptionKey, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Designer':
        id: c81032f7-b0ec-47ca-a236-e24d57b49ae3
  MarklogicVolume1data:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Volume'
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [0, !Ref AZ]
      Size: !Ref VolumeSizeData
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MarkLogic-GroupA-Host1-Volume1Adata
      VolumeType: !Ref VolumeType
      Encrypted: !If [UseVolumeEncryption, 'true', 'false']
      KmsKeyId: !If [HasCustomEBSKey, !Ref VolumeEncryptionKey, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
  MarklogicVolume1backup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Volume'
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [0, !Ref AZ]
      Size: !Ref VolumeSizeBackup
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MarkLogic-GroupA-Host1-Volume1Abackup
      VolumeType: !Ref VolumeType
      Encrypted: !If [UseVolumeEncryption, 'true', 'false']
      KmsKeyId: !If [HasCustomEBSKey, !Ref VolumeEncryptionKey, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
```

Updated the blockmapping within the Launch Configuration and the User Data script:

```
LaunchConfig1:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration'
    DependsOn:
      - InstanceSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      BlockDeviceMappings:
       - DeviceName: !Ref MarklogicVolume1root
         NoDevice: true
         Ebs: {}
       - DeviceName: !Ref MarklogicVolume1data
         NoDevice: true
         Ebs: {}        
       - DeviceName: !Ref MarklogicVolume1backup
         NoDevice: true
         Ebs: {} 
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      ImageId: !If [EssentialEnterprise, !FindInMap [LicenseRegion2AMI,!Ref 'AWS::Region',"Enterprise"], !FindInMap [LicenseRegion2AMI, !Ref 'AWS::Region', "BYOL"]]
      UserData: !Base64
        'Fn::Join':
          - ''
          - - MARKLOGIC_CLUSTER_NAME=
            - !Ref MarkLogicDDBTable
            - |+

            - MARKLOGIC_EBS_VOLUME1=
            - !Ref MarklogicVolume1root
            - ',:'
            - !Ref VolumeSize
            - '::'
            - !Ref VolumeType
            - |
              ::,*
            - | 
            - MARKLOGIC_EBS_VOLUME2=
            - !Ref MarklogicVolume1data
            - ',:'
            - !Ref VolumeSizeData
            - '::'
            - !Ref VolumeType
            - |
              ::,*
            - |  
            - MARKLOGIC_EBS_VOLUME3=
            - !Ref MarklogicVolume1backup
            - ',:'
            - !Ref VolumeSizeBackup
            - '::'
            - !Ref VolumeType
            - |
              ::,*  
            - |
              MARKLOGIC_NODE_NAME=NodeA#
            - MARKLOGIC_ADMIN_USERNAME=
            - !Ref AdminUser
            - |+

            - MARKLOGIC_ADMIN_PASSWORD=
            - !Ref AdminPass
            - |+

            - |
              MARKLOGIC_CLUSTER_MASTER=1
            - MARKLOGIC_LICENSEE=
            - !Ref Licensee
            - |+

            - MARKLOGIC_LICENSE_KEY=
            - !Ref LicenseKey
            - |+

            - MARKLOGIC_LOG_SNS=
            - !Ref LogSNS
            - |+

            - !If
              - UseVolumeEncryption
              - !Join
                - ''
                - - 'MARKLOGIC_EBS_KEY='
                  - !If
                    - HasCustomEBSKey
                    - !Ref VolumeEncryptionKey
                    - 'default'
              - ''
```

We are able to deploy the additional volumes but they are not mounting.  This is also interrupting the final configuration of the Ec2 instances as well because they also fail their load balancer health checks.  Any help or insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are eligible for support, I would suggest opening a ticket. help.marklogic.com

Answer (score 0):

The documentation talks about the steps needed to add an EBS volume to an instance.

[Creating an EBS Volume and Attaching it to an Instance](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2/managing#id_81403)

The brief over view is you need to:

- Create the Volume
- Attach the Volume (as /dev/sdf or higher)
- Run [init-volumes-from-system](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2/managing#id_72235)

Once that is done, you may also want to manually check the DynamoDB table associated with the CF Template, and ensure the entries have the updated volume information from the host.

Answer (score 0):

Michael's answer is how to add a EBS volume after a stack is created, this is different from the question which is how to define a CF template which pre-defines volumes.  If the volume is created but not mounted I recommend looking into the system logs, both marklogic logs and /var/log/messages for indications.  If that does not provide sufficient information to resolve then you should open a support ticket for assistance.